# Legend inside fieldset and clearing float left

Tags: html, css

I found on this site solution about move legend in fieldset from border to inside fieldset. http://codepen.io/vkjgr/pen/oFdBa When I want to do this i should use float left style on legend, but I should use clear both after legend ? This solution works on all browsers ? When I want clean I must use only clear both ?

```
<fieldset>
<legende> xyz </legend>
<div style="clear: both;"</div>
//
// Other divs and inputs
```

Comment: just give your `legend` tag a `width` of `100%`;

Comment: Ok, and this tag clear all problems with float ? When I set this tag next div will be under legend, but what witch next div ? Really I don't need clear ?

Comment: Yes, if you give the `legend` full width, then `clear: both` is not even necessary since there will be no room for the content below the legend to flow up

Comment: yes, you should `clear`, `Float` after `legend` otherwise the next line content will move upwards

Answer (score 1):

If you want to follow your own approach, it also works as shown below. Otherwise, `width:100%` on `legend` will also do.

```css
fieldset {
  padding: 2em;
}

legend {
  float: left;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    Hello
  </legend>
  <div class="clear">

  </div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque sunt ad facilis fugiat perferendis et fugit quas, accusantium, quod atque provident natus facere animi sed accusamus qui doloribus illo nesciunt.
  </p>
</fieldset>
```